# In Android Where is sms outgoing saved if that sms sended by class SmsManager, not application messager default

Tags: android

I want read information of sms outgoing that sended by class SmsManager in Android not by default application messenger in device. Any idea for help me? Many thank all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is saved by `SmsManager`. The messages are sent to their recipient over the mobile network, and that is it.

Individual *apps* may save messages that they *also* send via `SmsManager`. The details of which apps save what would depend upon the apps.

Comment: If nothing is saved by SmsManager, Have you any idea to resolve my problem? Can I rebuild SmsManager default of device  (or emulator) and reinstall it with my custome SmsManager to write log when any application send SMS with SmsManager?

Comment: @tungdx: You are welcome to make a custom build of the Android OS where you have hacked some logging code into `SmsManager`, then put that build into a ROM mod that you deploy on a device.

Comment: thank you, but I have another idea. It's is: I run a emulator (A) and run other amulator (B), then config (B) have number phone that application installed in (A) send to. I will read message received in (B) => I know about information SMS from application in (A). How I config (B) have number phone same that?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following two steps:
1. Send your message
2. **Insert** the message to "sent" messages box

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

String address = "address here";
String text = "text message here";

// Send you message
smsManager.sendTextMessage(address, null, text, null, null);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", address);
values.put("body", text);

// Insert the message to "sent" messages box
getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

PS: You can check the complete code [**here**](https://github.com/DailyEfforts/android_basics/blob/master/app/src/com/gmail/dailyefforts/android/basic/message/MessageActivity.java)

Comment: Thank for your comment but I mean that I send sms by SmsManger but not save it in any provider and want to get some infomation if sms has sended